# Where is the class AuthenticatedSubject for WebLogic's programmatic authentication?

Tags: java, security, authentication, weblogic

Greetings,

I'm trying to programmatically login through the provider in weblogic security realm from a servlet using this code:

```
    CallbackHandler handler = new URLCallbackHandler(userName, password);

    Subject subject = Authentication.login(handler);
    ServletAuthentication.runAs(subject, request);
```

These apis I've found in wls-api.jar (and weblogic.jar) in weblogic 10.3.4.

However,

compiling gives error:

```
cannot access weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject
    [javac] class file for weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject not found
    [javac]         ServletAuthentication.runAs(subject, request);
```

Now i find the package weblogic.security.acl.internal in the weblogic.jar (not the wls-api.jar) The class is not in either of them. Anyone know where i get them, or if i'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it's in:

`com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity.jar`

in the

`Middleware/modules` directory

**For JDeveloper 12.1.3, it's in**

`com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity.jar`

in the

`C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules` directory

Answer (score 1):

You can build a full client for Weblogic; this jar includes weblogic.servlet.security package.

Check this: [Using Weblogic JarBuilder tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to add the WebLogic 10.3 Remote-Client library to your view controller project